# Running use ant in java

Tags: java, ant, jar

Both compilation and JAR file creation is sucessful.

Running java file through ant file is producing error.

```
<project>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/Helloworld" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Helloworld"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run">
        <java jar="build/jar/Helloworld" fork="true"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Buildfile: `C:\Workspace\anttest\build.xml`

```
run:
 [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Helloworld
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Helloworld
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 [java] Could not find the main class: Helloworld. Program will exit.
 [java] Exception in thread "main" 
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ant ignores the return code from the java process by default  see : https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html#failonerror you can add the failonerror="true" attribute to change this behaviour ie:

Try changing

```
<target name="run">
    <java jar="build/jar/Helloworld" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

to

```
<target name="run">
    <java jar="build/jar/Helloworld" failonerror="true" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Your JAR file will not contain `HelloWorld` class.**

Comment: The NoClassDefFoundError already says that. Care to explain why?

Comment: I am answering the problem, obviously it is not obvious for the author of this question.